# How do I get a bot to respond to the right user ID?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a bot that automatically reacts to a specific user ID for an ongoing joke in a server. I've written the entire bot and it does react to messages, just not the ones with the user ID. When I tell it to react to my user ID, it doesn't react, when I tell it not to react to my user ID, it reacts to every message.

Can anyone help?

(The current code attempts to react to anyone that doesn't have my user ID, yet it still reacts to my ID.)

```py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    
@client.event 
async def on_message(message): 
    if (message.author.id != '318151890405687296'):
        print('banana');
        reaction = ""
        await message.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: [The docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id) suggest that `message.author.id` will be in integer, rather than a string, so that may be your first issue.

Comment: Python doesn't require parentheses around if statement conditions that are on a single line or semicolons (after `print('banana')`). I realize this could just be personal preference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problem here. To start with,

```py
if (message.author.id != '318151890405687296')
```

`1` is not the same as `'1'`, first is an integer, the 2nd is a string. `message.author.id` is an integer and you are checking it against a string. Even if the characters are the same, the check will never pass because `int != string`

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author.id != 318151890405687296:
        print('banana')
        reaction = ""
        await message.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)
```

Comment: Yeah, the first one was my problem, but I said in the post why it was !=.

Comment: @dopa Ah, I missed that bit. Sorry, corrected for it in the answer now